# Getting error when try to repeatedly read lines from file using the same buffer and file pointer

Tags: c, pointers

Here is my code:

```
int countTrans(FILE *fp, char *buf, int sesid){
  char str[10];
  int count = 0;
  size_t len;

  sprintf(str, "A%d:", sesid);
  while(-1 != getline(&buf, &len, fp)){
    if('T' == buf[0]){
      if(strstr(buf, str))
        count++;
    }
  }
  return count; 
}


int main(int argc, char **argv){
  FILE *ifp, *ofp;
  char *buf;
  size_t len;
  int count = 0, i = MAX_RAND;  // MAX_RAND = 200
  ...
  if(!(ifp = fopen(argv[1], "r"))){
    fprintf(stderr, "Can't open input file %s. Exit\n\n", argv[1]);
    exit(1);
  }
  buf = (char *)malloc(MAX_LEN);

  while(i){
    countTrans(ifp, buf, rand() % MAX_TRANS);
    i--;
    rewind(ifp);
  }
  ...
```

My purpose is to get a random session id, search that session id in a text file, and count how many time it appears, in a while loop which repeats 200 times. After the first time i malloc space for the buffer buf, i just keep passing it to the function countTrans() along with the same file pointer.

It compiles OK, and runs for about 10 iterations until i get this error:

```
getTrans(1516,0x7fff7885d300) malloc: *** error for object 0x101b2d000: pointer being realloc'd was not allocated

*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug

Abort trap: 6
```

i've checked other similar posts, most of them involve using realloc() but my code doesn't. And it seems the error occurred after the completion of the last successful countTrans() and before the start of a new iteration of countTrans(). 
Do i get a memory leak problem?

UPDATE:

It's a careless mistake. I forgot to initialize len inside countTrans() which should be:

```
  size_t len = MAX_LEN;
```

And the problem is solved. Thanks user3121023 for pointing that out.

Comment: You are calling `buf = (char *)malloc(MAX_LEN);`, but I do not see a `free()` statement anywhere.  Are you calling it?

Comment: @ryyker Yes, i call free(buf) outside the while loop, after all the counting is done.

Comment: @user3121023 Yes, that solves the problem! I've been careless. Thanks!